# Old double glaze: steam doesn't go

Tags: steam

I'm renting, bedroom has some big old double glazed window. The steam showed in pictures below formed a few months ago. It's still there and apparently will never go! As a result the view is totally spoiled.

Is there anything I can do to remove this steam?

[image]
[image]

Comment: A: get landlord to replace it. Or B: when lease is up, move out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. The seals in the window have failed, allowing moist air between the panes. This window has lost a lot of its insulating properties and the glazing needs to be replaced. Talk to the owner.